# Building a wood gate too hard for DIY newbie?

Tags: fence, gates, gate-post

The gate in my carport is falling apart, having been built very poorly by the previous home owner. The quote to replace from a reputable firm is $2,850.

I'm wondering, given the posts are already present, how hard would it be for a complete novice to (me) to re-build this properly? Does this seem doable?

Some questions for anyone whose built a gate like this:

- Would two hinges plus a diagonal wood brace be sufficient to prevent dragging? (WIDTH: 11' 6'' Double Swing)
- Do I build the two frames first, mount them, then attach the boards as shown? or assemble it all first then attach?
- For the frame, do I have to use a fancy joint style or can I simply screw the pieces together?
- Does the length of the hinge matter? Will it help prevent sagging if longer?
- Not seeing many plans online for this style fence. Any general tips?

[image: gate]

Comment: Other than a single broken board, what is wrong with it? It looks like an easy repair and maybe refinish to me.

Comment: Add a diagonal brace and « measure twice - cut once » it’s very difficult to put cut-off wood back....

Comment: Wood on the left side is ripped out, screws have torn out and likely would have to be replaced. Also hoping to do something to avoid wheels on bottom to let it swing open. Also the gates were built too long and won't close, they'd have to be sanded down to fit as well

Comment: Without the wheels at the opening side of the door, you willl need very beefy hinges

Comment: Agree that wheels are a must with this design. Rehab what you have. (Good excuse to buy a planer to fix the fit.) Spend your energies on other projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to build a gate properly you need the Z/reverse Z frame and build everything around that.

**How to design your fence properly**[image]

The key points are the intersections where the 45° lumber meets the horizontal and vertical lumber. You need good solid joints there. The rest is just decorations. For gates that wide I'd still put wheels on just because it'll be difficult to secure such a heavy load to the wall without some serious lags in very good brick.

[Here's an example of one:](http://blackdiamondfencing.com/dog-ear-fencing-with-a-simple-z-frame-double-gate-alternating-panels/)

[image: Example gate]